# Crear en Base de Datos MySQL una Tabla Estado_Vehiculo

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un programa para la administración de servicios de un taller de mecánica automotriz, en el hay tablas como:
Usuarios, Clientes, Personal, Servicios, Citas, Vehiculos y ESTADOdeVehiculo y una tabla ternaria que podria llamarse EstadoServicio_RepVehi 
(no prestemos atencion en los nombres es solo de ejemplo, lo importante es hacerse la idea)

La pregunta aqui es en ESTADOdeVehiculo esta tabla almacena los datos del estado de cada uno de los vehiculos al llegar al taller como si tiene gasolina, tiene todos sus cauchos, le falta un retrovisor, le sirve el aire acondicionado, tiene todas las luces, etc etc etc... 
En este caso que es lo correcto o mas factible? hacer la tabla con cada uno de esos campos o hacer un campo algo asi como TEXT para que se traiga todo en un formato de texto??

En la ventana de diseño en java tengo la ventana con una tabla y varios checkbox para afirmar si tiene o no cada uno de los campos.. pero no se como almacenarlos correctamente en la base de datos... si individualmente como varchar o boolean o como text todo junto en un especie de reporte :S es algo que a la final no creo que usen las personas que administren un taller pero creo que seria buena idea colocar esas opciones :S

Espero se me entienda la pregunta y disculpen si es algo confusa..

Aqui va una imagen de como llevo la base de datos :v tengo una duda con el uso del FOREIGN KEY Uds lo ven bien? colocare tambien el codigo n.n

Codigo SQL:

```
     -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering Lo hice con ayuda de Workbench pero cambie la manera de las foraneas ya que como las coloca workbench no conozco muy bien el uso de los CONSTRAINS y ese poco de puntitos...

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `tallermecanico_hd` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`a_usuarios`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`a_usuarios` (
  `nombre_u` INT NOT NULL,
  `contra_u` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `permiso` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nombre_u`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`b_personal`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`b_personal` (
  `cedula_p` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre_p` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `telefono_p` INT NULL,
  `email_p` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dir_p` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `cargo_p` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `f_contrato` DATE NULL,
  `status_p` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cedula_p`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`c_clientes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`c_clientes` (
  `cedula_c` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre_c` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_c` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `telefono_c` INT NOT NULL,
  `dir_c` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `email_c` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `empresa_c` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cedula_c`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`d_servicios`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`d_servicios` (
  `cod_serv` INT NOT NULL,
  `nomb_serv` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `descrip_serv` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_serv`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`e_vehiculos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`e_vehiculos` (
  `placa` INT NOT NULL,
  `marca` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `modelo` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `anio` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
  `observ` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `serial` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `puertas` INT,
  `motor` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `transmision` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `cedula_c` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`placa`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`cedula_c`)REFERENCES `c_clientes` (cedula_c)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`f_citas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`f_citas` (
  `id_cita` INT NOT NULL,
  `f_solicitud` DATETIME NULL,
  `f_pautada` DATETIME NULL,
  `falla_idk` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `observ_cita` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `placa` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cita`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`placa`) REFERENCES `e_vehiculos`(placa)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`g_est_vehiculo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`g_est_vehiculo` (
  `cod_estv` INT NOT NULL,
  `alarma` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `espejo_retrov` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `luces_int` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `cauchos` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `cauchorep` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `faros` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `obv_estv` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `placa` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_estv`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`placa`)REFERENCES `e_vehiculos` (placa)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`x_est_servicios`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tallermecanico_hd`.`x_est_servicios` (
  `f_inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `f_fin` DATETIME NULL,
  `resultado_s` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `est_result_s` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
-- fk
  `placa` INT NOT NULL,
  `cod_serv` INT NOT NULL,
  `cedula_p` INT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`f_inicio`,`placa`,`cod_serv`,`cedula_p`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`placa`)REFERENCES `e_vehiculos` (placa)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (`cedula_p`)REFERENCES `b_personal` (cedula_p)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

    FOREIGN KEY (`cod_serv`)REFERENCES `d_servicios`(cod_serv)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que si vas a necesitar hacer alguna operación estadística o necesitas saber algo particular  con los datos que propones de "gasolina", "cauchos", "retrovisores", etc., entonces es bueno hacer un campo para cada dato. Si lo único que quieres es leer como venía el vehículo y entregar ese dato tal y como lo escribiste, entonces un **TEXT** o un **VARCHAR** (x-bytes) te va a funcionar.

Si planeas crear los campos hay que pensar en que dominio actúan esos datos, por ejemplo, si creas el campo gasolina y tienes manera de cómo medir con cuanta gasolina viene el coche, entonces es un dominio numérico.

Supongamos que puedes medir la gasolina en mililitros, entonces podrías usar un **INT**, y así para 10 litros, se puede guardar 10,000. Como otro ejemplo, el campo que propones para almacenar si el aire acondicionado estaba funcional cuando llegó el auto, como solo vas a checar si esta útil o no, puede ser un **BOOLEAN** o un **TINYINT**.

Una última recomendación es crear por tu cuenta un texto en prosa, donde escribas los requerimientos que tiene este taller. Ahí mismo puedes darte mucho cuenta de que entidades (tablas) vas a necesitar y también te dará una buena idea de los atributos (campos) de las entidades y de sus relaciones.

Un saludo y espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia Abraham ..  tienes mucha razón creo que me tocara preguntarle mas a mis profesores e investigar un poco mas como trabajar de esa manera... aunque por ahora estoy viendo que me tocara usar varchar y que sea un teto informativo que si se tiene que cambiar se cambie.. y si es Si o No que aparezca la palabra Si o No rellenando el campo de la tabla :P

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es la siguiente: ¿Qué tanto conocimiento tienes en el manejo de archivos de texto o de campos de tipo texto? Las bases de datos relacionales fueron creadas para mejorar la administración de los datos que antes era tediosa con los archivos de texto.

Debes pensar en cálculos estadísticos, relaciones con otras tablas, agrupaciones, resúmenes, etc.

Los campos de tipo texto están diseñados para texto largos, por ejemplo, correos electrónicos, opiniones de los clientes, etc.

Si tu ventana tiene casillas de verificación lo más recomendable es una tabla dedicada al estado del vehículo con cada atributo como campo y de tipo booleano. Si por ejemplo requieres almacenar la cantidad de gasolina que sea de tipo numérico.

Al final la tabla te facilita las cosas y los cálculos estadísticos. ¿Te imaginas lo complicado de relacionar tu tabla estadoVehiculo en formato texto con otras tablas?

Te recomendaría archivos de texto para un análisis de datos pero en Python, no con Java.

Además, Java no tiene muchas funciones que faciliten la manipulación de campos y de archivos de tipo texto.

Comment: Gracias Jaime! tienes razón haré caso a tu sugerencia! Pero no entendi muy bien lo de la **tabla dedicada con cada atributo como campo y de tippo booleano** ... el profesor me ha dicho que por ahora no me preocupe tanto por eso >.< que respuesta de parte del profe.. aunque me alivia un poco a la vez me deja con la duda.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la tabla *Citas* es la tabla donde se registrarán las visitas de los vehículos al taller (No le encontraría sentido si lo agregas en la tabla `Vechiculos`).

Viéndolo de esa forma, yo consideraría poner los estados en que llegan los autos al taller en la tabla `Citas`, ya que necesitamos saber el estado de los autos en cada una de las citas (Esto estaría bien si los estados ya están definidos, y si no son muchos). (**Ver primera imagen**)

Si creas una tabla aparte para el estado creo que no quedaría muy bien, porque la relación será de *uno a uno*, ya que todos los vehículos no llegan en el mismo estado, excluyendo algunos casos, a menos que los estados definidos, sean muchos (aunque para eso también tienes la tercera opción) (**Ver Segunda imagen**).

[image: Primera Imagen]

Y si los estados, se definen dinámicamente sería mejor tener una tabla para definir los estados, según se requiera, y una tabla pivote para relacionarlo con la cita.

[image: Segunda Imagen]

Yo me quedaría con la primera opción, pero depende de lo que necesites.

Comment: Wow amigo con gráficos y todos muchas gracias por tu ayuda pero de veras no he entendido mucho tu idea y comprendo que mi culpa por no explicar bien como va la base de datos como puedo hacer para montar un modelo de mas o menos lo pensado? el modelo relacional me refiero saco la imagen y la publico eso podria ayudar cierto? aunque eso podria generar mas dudas porque seguro tiene fallas >.<

Comment: Sería una buena idea que compartieras el modelo de tu BD para poder saber, según tu modelo, donde sería el mejor lugar para agregar el estado. En los ejemplos que compartí contigo incluí algunas tablas que pensé tienen que estar en tu modelo, pero eso no quiere decir que tu modelo tiene que estar cercano a lo que yo consideré, todos pensamos diferente y tenemos diversas formas para resolver las cosas. Si tu modelo tienes fallas, no hay problema, todo estamos para aprender :D